# Apply argMax over multiple columns in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

My Clickhouse table has a primary key column (`pk`), an insert timestamp column (`insert_ts`), and a bunch of data columns. I'd like to get the latest value for each data column. My query could look like this:

```
SELECT pk, argMax(data1, insert_ts), argMax(data2, insert_ts), ... GROUP BY pk
```

That's very verbose, and I'd prefer to use a wildcard with EXCEPT/APPLY like this:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(insert_ts) APPLY(argMax) GROUP BY pk
```

But I have no way to specify the second argument to `argMax`. Any ideas?

I'm interested both in answers to this specific question, and also to answers to the XY-problem that propose a different way to structure my table.

Comment: no way https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/27877

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the Clickhouse team for implementing a solution really quickly!

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(insert_ts) APPLY(x->argMax(x,insert_ts)) GROUP BY pk
```

For the XY problem, Clickhouse offers the ReplacingMergeTree engine for explicitly keeping only the latest rows:

- https://altinity.com/blog/2020/4/14/handling-real-time-updates-in-clickhouse
- https://kb.altinity.com/engines/mergetree-table-engine-family/replacingmergetree

Comment: The latest rows are left only within one partition and after merge parts in the partition. If you have big partitions or frequent inserts or insert into multiple partitions simultaneously, you will be faced with multiple rows with the same PK in ReplacingMergeTree. And, of course, this stuff works only within one shard.