# ClickHouse lambda function into APPLY select modifier

Tags: lambda, clickhouse

I’ working on a query that pretend to provide from a pk group by aggregation, the values that correspond to the max value of a timestamp field I have.

I base my code in the solution proposed for this question:
[Apply argMax over multiple columns in Clickhouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68849789/apply-argmax-over-multiple-columns-in-clickhouse)

My resultant code has this form:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(`Timestamp`) APPLY(i->argmax(i,`Timestamp`))
FROM some_table
GROUP BY pk;
```

I’m getting the following error:

*DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 35 ('->') (line 1, col 35): ->argMax(i,Timestamp)) ……*

I’m try to avoid to use a much verbose query specifying in the SELECT an argmax() for each column, I have more have 100 columns…
Does anyone some ideas about?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

ClickHouse release v21.10, 2021-10-16

Support lambda argument for APPLY column transformer which allows applying functions with more than one argument. This is for #27877. #27901 (Amos Bird).

```sql
SELECT
    pk,
    max(Timestamp),
    * EXCEPT (Timestamp, pk) APPLY i -> argMax(i, Timestamp)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        1 AS Timestamp,
        2 AS a,
        3 AS c,
        4 AS pk
)
GROUP BY pk

Query id: 14afac7a-bd2f-421e-8240-f0490d1cc4a3

┌─pk─┬─max(Timestamp)─┬─argMax(a, Timestamp)─┬─argMax(c, Timestamp)─┐
│  4 │              1 │                    2 │                    3 │
└────┴────────────────┴──────────────────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

It's unusable for 100 columns. It will execute forever. The idea of the columnar databases that you have 500 columns but query a few of them.

Comment: Thank you very much. The main problem is I'm working with release v21.3.9.83.